# Google Sheet Query referencing cell data as part of Sheet Name Source

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have been working on querying multiple sheets of data and would like the text string from one of the cells to determine which sheet that row is querying but can not figure out how to do it. This is the most recent formula I have tried:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT("B"&"2")&"!"&$2:$1000)
```

Cell B2 contains the name of the other sheet I am trying to query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(B2&"!2:1000"))
```

or:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(B2&"!B2:B1000"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the final Formula used:

=QUERY(INDIRECT(B2&"!2:1000"), "SELECT E WHERE A = date '"& text(C2, "yyyy-mm-dd") &"' and B contains '"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(D2, " " , ""),"AM", ""), "PM", "")&"' ")